# TemplateResponseMixin requires either a definition of 'template_name' or an implementation of 'get_template_names()' in DRF

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

i am trying to confirm email address in django rest framework but i am getting the error

i changed url patterns and import confirm_email view form allauth but still getting the error

## urls.py

```
 from allauth.account.views import confirm_email
    urlpatterns = [
    path('rest-auth/registration/account-confirm-email/(?P<key>.+)/', confirm_email, name='account_confirm_email'),
    ]
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics

#for facebook authentication
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook.views import FacebookOAuth2Adapter
from rest_auth.registration.views import SocialLoginView
from . import models
from . import serializers


class UserListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = models.CustomUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.UserSerializer

class FacebookLogin(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = FacebookOAuth2Adapter
```

Comment: can you add your `view` code?

Comment: i have updated my code

Comment: can't see `confirm_email` in view

Comment: i think confirm_email is a default view

Comment: is this part of some third-party package `from allauth.account.views import confirm_email`

Comment: yes this is from allauth

Comment: this package `allauth` is expecting a template path for email confirmation, as error message suggests and you can take a look at source code here 
https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/views.py

that gets resolved from settings `app_settings.TEMPLATE_EXTENSION`

make sure `TEMPLATE_EXTENSION` is defined in settings file